# create a substitute of Uint8array on android 2.x

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developping an application on phonegap for android. I would like that the application can work on android 2.3.3 and more. 
I use Uint8array on my code. this work on android 4 but not on android 2. I've got this error:

can't find variable: Uint8array

I do some research and found that uint8array is not supported on android2. I would like to know if there is a similiar function or a library that work on android 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the answer.

you have to create a js file. In this one paste this code:

```
(function() {
try {
var a = new Uint8Array(1);
return; //no need
} catch(e) { }

function subarray(start, end) {
return this.slice(start, end);
}

function set_(array, offset) {
if (arguments.length < 2) offset = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i, ++offset)
  this[offset] = array[i] & 0xFF;
}

// we need typed arrays
function TypedArray(arg1) {
var result;
if (typeof arg1 === "number") {
   result = new Array(arg1);
   for (var i = 0; i < arg1; ++i)
     result[i] = 0;
} else
   result = arg1.slice(0);
result.subarray = subarray;
result.buffer = result;
result.byteLength = result.length;
result.set = set_;
if (typeof arg1 === "object" && arg1.buffer)
  result.buffer = arg1.buffer;

return result;
}

window.Uint8Array = TypedArray;
window.Uint32Array = TypedArray;
window.Int32Array = TypedArray;
})();


(function() {
if ("response" in XMLHttpRequest.prototype ||
  "mozResponseArrayBuffer" in XMLHttpRequest.prototype || 
  "mozResponse" in XMLHttpRequest.prototype ||
  "responseArrayBuffer" in XMLHttpRequest.prototype)
return;
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, "response", {
get: function() {
  return new Uint8Array( new VBArray(this.responseBody).toArray() );
}
});
})();

(function() {
if ("btoa" in window)
return;

var digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

window.btoa = function(chars) {
var buffer = "";
var i, n;
for (i = 0, n = chars.length; i < n; i += 3) {
  var b1 = chars.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  var b2 = chars.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xFF;
  var b3 = chars.charCodeAt(i + 2) & 0xFF;
  var d1 = b1 >> 2, d2 = ((b1 & 3) << 4) | (b2 >> 4);
  var d3 = i + 1 < n ? ((b2 & 0xF) << 2) | (b3 >> 6) : 64;
  var d4 = i + 2 < n ? (b3 & 0x3F) : 64;
  buffer += digits.charAt(d1) + digits.charAt(d2) + digits.charAt(d3) +      digits.charAt(d4);
}
return buffer;
}; 
})();
```

And just include this javascript before you use UInt8array